# Analysis of influence against weighted edges and attributes

Tags: regression, data-visualization, social-network

I have network data of organizations and weighted links between these organisations, the weight indicates level of trade between these organisations.  I have attribute files against each organisation relating to the number of environmentally friendly production technique they have initiated - for example, in response to environmental legislation.

What I would like to calculate is the influence an organization will have in changing an adjacent organisations production techniques, according to the amount of trade between them and the number of changes in the past.

For example, if environmentally friendly organisation 'A' conducts a large amount of trade with 'B' but little with 'C' then what is the likelihood of 'B' or 'C' changing their production techniques.  Thus, throughout the whole network organizations with a high weighted connectivity with a historical tendency to change techniques are likely to be central to changing production platforms within a particular industry.

I am a little lost with how to approach this, it seems to be some form of weighted centrality against the given attribute, therefore I feel I would have to approach this in two or more stages.  I would want to visualise this on a network diagram, with influential organisations larger nodes and all those likely to be influenced in a certain colour.